# Applying an argument in mapStateToProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

This is a simple component that displays a counter and two buttons to increment/decrement it.

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>{this.props.counter}</h1>
        <button type="button" onClick={this.props.increment}>
          increment
        </button>
        <button type="button" onClick={this.props.decrement}>
          decrement
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }    
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  counter: state.counter
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  increment: () => dispatch({ type: "INCREMENT" }),
  decrement: () => dispatch({ type: "DECREMENT" })
});

App.propTypes = {
  counter: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  increment: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  decrement: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

This is a minimal example, but in real life, I need a lot of props in `mapStateToProps`, that all require the `state` arg. I am trying to apply the `state` arg to all the values in the `mapStateToProps` object return. Something like this:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  user: getCurrentUser(state),
  page: getPage(state),
  // ... f(state)
});
```

What I tried:

```
const mapStateToProps = state =>
  _.mapValues(
    {
      counter: state => state.counter
    },
    state
  );
```

I got this error: `proxyConsole.js:56 Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop`counter`of type`boolean`supplied to 'App', expected 'number'.`
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: and why does my boss won't let me code in ClojureScript?

Answer (score 1):

The error says that `counter` is a `boolean` and you're expecting a `number`. As you can see at the bottom of your code where the **propTypes** are specified.

```
App.propTypes = {
    counter: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    increment: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    decrement: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};
```

Make sure `counter` is a `number`.

Comment: It is. The code just runs fine with the first version.